# Parsing JSON data in an ASP.NET repeater control

Tags: asp.net, json, parsing, repeater

I'm building a small test prototype where I'm pulling data from a back-end SQL database using a repeater and an entity data source.  One of my columns returns data in JSON format.

Question: is there any way to parse JSON data within a repeater (or, for that matter, any other ASP.NET data control)?  I was hoping that there'd be a relatively easy way to do this, but I'm discovering that's not the case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe asp.net comes with json.net that you can use to parse your data.  You could describe to the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) to customize rendering if your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the JSON data, but the real question is *where* you want to parse it; on the client or on the server? Assuming you want to parse the data on the server, you can use the `ItemDataBound` event and the `JavaScriptSerializer` class:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var jsonData = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "JsonData");

    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(jsonData);                
}
```

Comment: I would definitely prefer to parse it on the server side.  Let me play with this code a bit and see if I can get it to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the stupid question: what's the correct syntax for calling the Deserialize dictionary from the inline code?

Comment: I don't think you can with inline code. I would iterate over the dictionary and add the data to a `PlaceHolder` in the repeater from the `ItemDataBound` event handler.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand.  Let me go play some more.

Comment: Still struggling with this.  What's the best way to iterate over the dictionary?  I tried a foreach, but can't seem to get it to work.  (Forgive me; I've never used the Dictionary object before.)

Comment: A little more info, if this helps: each JSON entry is associated with a numeric primary key, numbered 1, 2, etc.  Note: the numbers are NOT consecutive!  Ideally, I would like to associate the dictionary entries using these IDs as the key.